How to apply `select` filter to a video URL with `ffprobe` to get scene change timestamps?
I'm trying to use ffprobe to detect scene changes in a video hosted online, with this command:
ffprobe -show_frames -of compact=p=0 -f lavfi "movie=https://example.com/video.mp4,select=gt(scene\,0.1)"

But I get this error:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x6000002cd8f0] Error processing filtergraph: No such file or directory
movie=https://example.com/video.mp4,select=gt(scene\,0.1): No such file or directory

My goal is to produce a list of timestamps when scene changes occur. I know ffprobe supports online files, but I can't figure out how to combine the URL and the select filter properly. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Apparently the colon in the URL needs to be escaped, similarly to how it's done when working with pipes. Here's the relevant resource:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5229

Could you include the corrected arguments here in your answer? If that link goes bad, much of the benefit of your answer goes with it. Adding a corrected set of arguments here will make this answer stay relevant even if the link goes bad.

Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.
